# Solspace importer : A Unique Field Element with valid EE Field Are Required

Tags: solspace, solspace-importer

I'm using solspace importer (latest version) to import members in EE v2.10.1

In the importer settings form, I have a row **Additional Member Fields**
There is a select where I can select custom fields and a button [Add field].

When I click the Add Field button I get this error :

An Error Was Encountered
A Unique Field Element with valid EE Field Are Required.

I don't have a clue about what it means...

**EDIT : In fact clicking that button submits the form while there are still blank fields. Is that a bug ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a hint from Nicolas @ solspace's support, we found that a little htacces was blocking access to a javascript file.

**Below code breaks solspace's importer** (and everything member related)

```
# Prevent direct access to EE Member area
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (member)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/404 [R=301,L]
```

As these two lines are quite widely used It might help someone else running into the same issue.

Comment: Incidentally the file that needed access was called `members.js`, which would fulfill the above rewrite rule. An unfortunate coincidence :)